# Print method in R for function that prints summary even when function output is assigned to an object

Tags: r, methods, printing, package

I am creating a new R package and am adding in a function that will produce a list. See an example of how this function is working below. I have assigned a print method to this function that provides a separate interpretation/descriptive summary of the output. See an example below.

```
fun_example <- function(xvar, yvar){
  # Plots
  plot1 = ggplot2::ggplot(data.frame(xvar, yvar), ggplot2::aes(x = xvar, y = yvar)) + ggplot2::geom_line()
  plot2 = ggplot2::ggplot(data.frame(xvar, yvar), ggplot2::aes(x = xvar, y = yvar)) + ggplot2::geom_line()
  plots <- list(plot1, plot2)
  
  # Correlation
  Cor <- cor(xvar, yvar)
  
  result <- list(plots, Cor)
  names(result) <- c("plots", "Cor")
  class(result) <- "fun_example"
  suppressMessages(return(result))
}

#-------------------------------------------
## S3Methods print() // Updated 06.02.2021
#-------------------------------------------

#' S3Methods for Printing
#'
#' @name prints
#'
#' @aliases
#' print.fun_example
#'
#' @usage
#' \method{print}{fun_example}(x, ...)
#'
#' @description Prints for \code{package_example} objects
#'
#' @param x Object from \code{package_example} package
#'
#' @param ... Additional arguments
#'
#' @return Prints \code{package_example} object
#'
# Print fun_example
#' @export
print.fun_example <- function(x, ...){
  cat("Visually inspect each plot in the plots object to check for linearity.\n")
  if(x$Cor > 0.8){
    cat("A correlation greater than 0.8 was found.")
  } else {
    cat("A correlation less than or equal to 0.8 was found.")
  }
}
```

ISSUE:

When the function is run by itself and not assigned to an object, the print function works as expected. The actual output, a list, does not appear in the console. However, users of the function should save this into an object.

```
> fun_example(xvar = 1:3, yvar = 4:6)
Visually inspect each plot in the plots object to check for linearity.
A correlation greater than 0.8 was found.
```

When the function's output is assigned to an object, the output (list) is assigned to an object BUT the print method does not show anything in the console.

```
> test <- fun_example(xvar = 1:3, yvar = 4:6)
>
```

WHAT I WANT TO SEE:

What I want to do is specify the print method in such a way that the list will be assigned to an object and the print will show up in the console, such as:

```
> test <- fun_example(xvar = 1:3, yvar = 4:6)
Visually inspect each plot in the plots object to check for linearity.
A correlation greater than 0.8 was found.
```

Users can manually type the example below by putting the assignment in parantheses, but I'd rather have this automatically done by the functions.

```
> (test <- fun_example(xvar = 1:3, yvar = 4:6))
Visually inspect each plot in the plots object to check for linearity.
A correlation greater than 0.8 was found.
```

Specifying the prints within the function rather than using a print method does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A custom `print()` method will only run when an object is actually `print()`ed. When you type a value at the console, the final expression is implicitly `print()`ed. That printing does not happen when you do an assignment. So unless you explicitly call `print()` or wrap the assignment in `()`, nothing triggers the `print()` function. If you need it to print no matter what, you might consider adding code to your function to `cat()` a message or create a `message()` that's displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per @MrFlick's comment, I changed the function to:

```
fun_example <- function(xvar, yvar){
  # Plots
  plot1 = ggplot2::ggplot(data.frame(xvar, yvar), ggplot2::aes(x = xvar, y = yvar)) + ggplot2::geom_line()
  plot2 = ggplot2::ggplot(data.frame(xvar, yvar), ggplot2::aes(x = xvar, y = yvar)) + ggplot2::geom_line()
  plots <- list(plot1, plot2)
  
  # Correlation
  Cor <- cor(xvar, yvar)

message("Visually inspect each plot in the plots object to check for linearity.\n")
  if(x$Cor > 0.8){
    message("A correlation greater than 0.8 was found.")
  } else {
    message("A correlation less than or equal to 0.8 was found.")
  }
  
  result <- list(plots, Cor)
  names(result) <- c("plots", "Cor")
  class(result) <- "fun_example"
  suppressMessages(return(result))
}
```

Note that this didn't work for me if the messages did not come before the return() function.

Comment: No code will ever run after a `return()` call in a function. When `return()` is encountered, a function immediately returns. That's not really unique to `message()` at all.